# How to query oracle database with large local CLOB (spatial) data

Tags: sql, oracle, geospatial

I'm trying to query our production database with spatial data. This data comes from another database, and I have it saved in a text file.

My current query looks like this, which works well for data up to 32K.

```sql
select * from PLEJ.deljordstykke d
inner join PLEJ.geometri g on d.id = g.id
inner join PLEJ.deljordstykke_termin_relation dt on dt.deljordstykke_id = d.id
where d.udgaaet = 0
and dt.termin_id = 1 
and dt.aktiv = 1
and sdo_filter(g.geometri, 
                sdo_util.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(:geo), 
                'querytype=window') = 'TRUE';
```

The problem is that my geometry is bigger than 32K. I figured I could read that data from a file, but as I understand it, this is only possible if the data is located on the same server. So my question is, how can I adapt this query for large locally stored geometries, while only having read access to this database? Is it possible?

Comment: you could make this query work for larger data by adding right indexes

Comment: Are you tied to doing this through a client (Like SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer etc.); or are you able to write a program, e.g. a small Java program to run the query over JDBC, which could read from the local file and bind the text as a CLOB directly? (I imagine you could do it in Python too but not familiar with that.)

Comment: @AlexPoole I kinda thought about doing that as well... If no one has a better solution I might need to do that.